# Run PowerShell command before installation

Tags: powershell, inno-setup

So I have this command:

```
[Run]
Filename: "powershell.exe"; Parameters: "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Minimized -Command Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath {sd}\CFRK -Force"; Flags: runascurrentuser
```

It works well but I need it to run before installation and after defining installation folder. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I recommend fixing the spelling mistake in the title.

Comment: @StayOnTarget: I just fixed the spelling mistake (Waits for approval).